# Is there a standard way to incorporate target continuous variable in DBSCAN, and use the model for inference?

Tags: r, clustering, dbscan

I'm trying to use a density based clustering method on this data, where Y is the target variable Y and X is the independent variable (both are continuous):

Snip 1 is hex-bin-plot of X and Y:
[image]
So i am trying to create clusters of the data using the density based clustering method, packages fpc and dbscan in R. A result was got as below:

[image: DBScan to cluster data]
Now that this was done on training dataset, i need to cluster the test dataset also. My question is, how to prepare the Y dimension (target dimension) for test data? I was thinking to try target encoding on bins of size 0.1 in the train data, but it may not serve the purposes for clustering well.

Thanks in advance for any ideas around this

Comment: Why do you wish to use clustering?  You have access to labels Y, why not just treat this as a standard supervised regression problem?

Comment: What is Y actually? Do you have it for each sample?

Comment: Your data does not seem very predictable with only ndvi_ne as a feature. With X around 0 there are both cases with Y=0 and Y>200

Comment: Clustering is *not* meant to be a predictive method! Nor does DBSCAN sign labels to new samples. **If you want to predict a numerical value, use regression!**

Comment: Last but not least, the data doesn't show any actual clusters, but rather the x axis looks rather normal distributed to me...

Comment: @jonnor - agreed,  X is not predictable as it is. So, the idea was to add the Y as a predictive factor in the 2nd dimension - as the distribution of data points with both X and Y is very concentrated around the center. I was thinking of target encoding as a possible method to 'capture' the value of Y :)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse - thanks for the input. The idea was to assume that the hexbin 2-D distribution  with X and Y values would apply for test data as well, and then somehow 'capture' the value of Y for test data! In my thinking, target encoding, which is popular method in Kaggle, seems to be a way to capture the influence of the Y variable

Comment: That is called regression, isn't it?

Comment: No. I am trying to add a new feature to the test dataset, which is a cluster tag ID to each datapoint as a result of the dbscan algorithm. Given the hexplot above, the clustering seems clear when both the X and Y are fed to the dbscan algorithm. while this is clear for training data, it is not clear for test data since Y is absent in test data. The target encoding / mean encoding idea from kaggle seems to provide a way to get the Y as a feature set for test data so that dbscan can be run on the test data , so, i was checking whether there was any other way.

Comment: Will you have access to Y for new data coming in? (not part of training set)? From how I read your post, it sounds like it is the target variable to predict - which would not be available for new samples.

Comment: yes, that is correct. I am currently using mean encoding after binning the train X variable, and then using that mean encoded feature (say, Y-hat) along with the test X variable to predict a cluster ID for test data based on a clustering model trained on the training X and Y.  Was wondering whether anyone had done something like this before and could give some pointers!